# Using BOOST::UBLAS and FFTW together for image processing

Tags: c++, boost, fftw

Is there a possibility to use a boost matrix along FFTW? if so how do you do it?
what i basically have is

```
QPixmap pixmap("lena.bmp");
// resize input image
pixmap = pixmap.copy(512,512,128,128);
pixmap = pixmap.scaled(128,128);
QImage image = pixmap.toImage();
QRgb col;

int g;
int width = pixmap.width();
int height = pixmap.height();
matrix<double> m(width,height);
for (int j = 0; j < m.size2(); j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size1(); i++)
    {
        m(i,j) = 0;

        m(i,j) = qGray(image.pixel(i,j));

    }
}
```

I want to perform FFTW on the matrix 'm' and then redisplay the fft of the image. how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do is first read your image into an array, then apply the FFTW as per your needs on this array and then fill this array into a boost ublas matrix and then use it.

```
int a[width][height];
for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
    a[i][j] = qGray(image.pixel(i,j));

    }
}
//apply fftw

matrix<double> m(width,height);
for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
    m(i,j) = fft_a[i][j];

    }
}
```

I hope this works